# Image classification - first production coding try

Tags: python, image-classification, machine-learning-model

***TLDR***

Experienced non-ML developer has done the basics to learn beginner ML, now needs to put it to real use  - looking for help.  *...I guess a common/frequent situation for many!*

*For mods - I've tried to make this as specific as possible, not looking for opinions etc.  I've also searched for related questions without finding anything directly related here.*

***Background***

**Me**: I'm an experienced coder and scientific algorithm developer, with a strong science/maths background, (ie 20+ years experience) who has only previously used non-ML (ie scikit-image, openCV) algorithms for image analysis type tasks.

I've had no problems doing several background beginner ML courses (Several of Andrew Ng's etc) and understand the basic theory, coding/implementation of all the beginner level stuff etc pretty well.  *(ie I could write my own SVM/CNN/NN classification model using just numpy if I was forced to)*.

***Problem***

I want to start using ML to perform some basic image classification **in production use** to replace current 'classical' image analysis based classification techniques.

or...

I've learned a bunch of theory using somewhat toy examples and likely old'ish libraries, now I need to do some 'real' work using current libraries.

***Specific Problem***

Luckily, the images I need to classify are a) not many classes (5-10), b) quite simple and readily distinguishable.  Some conceptual examples shown below.

***Questions***

(note my problem is classifying the images, *not* object detection within the image)

- For the examples below, would a basic SVM, neural network etc type model be sufficient, (even accounting for the small translation/rotation variance with the objects within), or would a CNN/equivalent be best?
- Given my complete lack of exposure to latest/greatest models/algorithms/libraries, are their any canned type models/libraries that would simplify model generation/deployment?
- Given production deployment would be using python 3.8, on AWS micro/small instances (ie no GPU, but more importantly constraints on disk space, what library (Tensorflow, Sklearn, PyTorch etc) would have a smaller footprint from CPU and disk-space requirements?
- For someone doing their first theory->production try, are their any "dont do this" or "make sure you do this" type gotchas that would be good for me to know?

[image] [image]  [image]  [image]  [image]

***Caveats***

The 'objects' within each image may be translated and/or rotated by a small amount - maybe up to 10-15% of the image dimensions and +/- 10 degrees:

[image]

Comment: You could try a pretrained Keras model which will likely work well in many cases (probably over-engineered in you case). Check this model on github: https://github.com/Bixi81/Python-ml/blob/master/keras_pretrained_imagerec_multiclass.py

Comment: Great - thanks Peter